# How i can put my node.js app in an existing page?

Tags: php, node.js

I have a PHP page, with all my website important logic and i want to just put my node.js chat there without changing the PHP logic, maybe like Youtube's embed player or something like that. It's possible? 
Or maybe i should think in changing my chat app to PHP chat service?

I'm new with Node.js, i love the socket.io idea, it's faster than other chat services, but i didn't find anything in google, i don't know how to proceed. Someone can help me? Thanks!

My app code (if can help)

```js
var app = require('http').createServer(resposta); // Criando o servidor
var fs = require('fs'); // Sistema de arquivos
var io = require('socket.io')(app); // Socket.IO
var usuarios = []; // Lista de usuários
var ultimas_mensagens = []; // Lista com ultimas mensagens enviadas no chat

app.listen(3000);

console.log("Aplicação está em execução...");

// Função principal de resposta as requisições do servidor
function resposta (req, res) {
 var arquivo = "";
 if(req.url == "/"){
  arquivo = __dirname + '/index2.html';
 }else{
  arquivo = __dirname + req.url;
 }
 fs.readFile(arquivo,
  function (err, data) {
   if (err) {
    res.writeHead(404);
    return res.end('Página ou arquivo não encontrados');
   }

   res.writeHead(200);
   res.end(data);
  }
 );
}

io.on("connection", function(socket){
 // Método de resposta ao evento de entrar
 socket.on("entrar", function(apelido, callback){
  if(!(apelido in usuarios)){
   socket.apelido = apelido;
   usuarios[apelido] = socket; // Adicionadno o nome de usuário a lista armazenada no servidor

   // Enviar para o usuário ingressante as ultimas mensagens armazenadas.
   for(indice in ultimas_mensagens){
    socket.emit("atualizar mensagens", ultimas_mensagens[indice]);
   }


   var mensagem = "[ " + pegarDataAtual() + " ] " + apelido + " acabou de entrar na sala";
   var obj_mensagem = {msg: mensagem, tipo: 'sistema'};

   io.sockets.emit("atualizar usuarios", Object.keys(usuarios)); // Enviando a nova lista de usuários
   io.sockets.emit("atualizar mensagens", obj_mensagem); // Enviando mensagem anunciando entrada do novo usuário

   armazenaMensagem(obj_mensagem); // Guardando a mensagem na lista de histórico

   callback(true);
  }else{
   callback(false);
  }
 });


 socket.on("enviar mensagem", function(dados, callback){

  var mensagem_enviada = dados.msg;
  var usuario = dados.usu;
  if(usuario == null)
   usuario = ''; // Caso não tenha um usuário, a mensagem será enviada para todos da sala
  if (mensagem_enviada.match("^/")) {
   mensagem_enviada = mensagem_enviada;
  }
  else {
   mensagem_enviada = "[ " + pegarDataAtual() + " ] " + socket.apelido + " diz: " + mensagem_enviada;
  }
  
  var obj_mensagem = {msg: mensagem_enviada, tipo: ''};
  
  if(mensagem_enviada == '/kick'){
   delete usuarios[socket.apelido];
  var mensagem = "[ " + pegarDataAtual() + " ] " + socket.apelido + " saiu da sala";
  var obj_mensagem = {msg: mensagem, tipo: 'sistema'};


  // No caso da saída de um usuário, a lista de usuários é atualizada
  // junto de um aviso em mensagem para os participantes da sala  
  io.sockets.emit("atualizar usuarios", Object.keys(usuarios));
  io.sockets.emit("atualizar mensagens", obj_mensagem);

  armazenaMensagem(obj_mensagem);
  
  socket.disconnect();
  } 
  else{
  if(usuario == ''){
   io.sockets.emit("atualizar mensagens", obj_mensagem);
   armazenaMensagem(obj_mensagem); // Armazenando a mensagem
  }else{
   obj_mensagem.tipo = 'privada';
   socket.emit("atualizar mensagens", obj_mensagem); // Emitindo a mensagem para o usuário que a enviou
   usuarios[usuario].emit("atualizar mensagens", obj_mensagem); // Emitindo a mensagem para o usuário escolhido
  }
  }
  callback();
 });

 socket.on("disconnect", function(){
  delete usuarios[socket.apelido];
  var mensagem = "[ " + pegarDataAtual() + " ] " + socket.apelido + " saiu da sala";
  var obj_mensagem = {msg: mensagem, tipo: 'sistema'};


  // No caso da saída de um usuário, a lista de usuários é atualizada
  // junto de um aviso em mensagem para os participantes da sala  
  io.sockets.emit("atualizar usuarios", Object.keys(usuarios));
  io.sockets.emit("atualizar mensagens", obj_mensagem);

  armazenaMensagem(obj_mensagem);
 });

});


// Função para apresentar uma String com a data e hora em formato DD/MM/AAAA HH:MM:SS
function pegarDataAtual(){
 var dataAtual = new Date();
 var dia = (dataAtual.getDate()<10 ? '0' : '') + dataAtual.getDate();
 var mes = ((dataAtual.getMonth() + 1)<10 ? '0' : '') + (dataAtual.getMonth() + 1);
 var ano = dataAtual.getFullYear();
 var hora = (dataAtual.getHours()<10 ? '0' : '') + dataAtual.getHours();
 var minuto = (dataAtual.getMinutes()<10 ? '0' : '') + dataAtual.getMinutes();
 var segundo = (dataAtual.getSeconds()<10 ? '0' : '') + dataAtual.getSeconds();

 var dataFormatada = dia + "/" + mes + "/" + ano + " " + hora + ":" + minuto + ":" + segundo;
 return dataFormatada;
}

// Função para guardar as mensagens e seu tipo na variável de ultimas mensagens
function armazenaMensagem(mensagem){
 if(ultimas_mensagens.length > 5){
  ultimas_mensagens.shift();
 }

 ultimas_mensagens.push(mensagem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why not to just connect to your host on given port (3000 at this moment) from client-side script?

Comment: @DanielKucal how i can do this?

Comment: var socket = io('http:// yourdomain.com:3000');
See socket.io docs: http://socket.io/docs/